# XEN VGA Passthrough reboot DomU error

Tags: vga, xen

I currently have the following XEN Setup:

XEN 4.2.1
Kernel 3.8.0-25, self compiled with XEN PCI Backend include in the kernel
AMD HD6450
AMD HD6850
ASRock87Z Extreme6
iCore 4770 (not K!)

Goal ist to run two Windows 7 DomU's. One as htpc, one as working station with VGA Passthrough to Windows 7 DomU's. I have not installes GPLPV Drivers until now.

I did get Windows 7 to work with the HD6450, passthrough as as Secondary GPU. When i passthrough the HD6850 ist works after a clean reboot of the host dom0. But when I reboot the Windows 7 DomU the display is not comming up again. This is working with the 6450 but not with the 6850.

Has anybody encountered a similar problem or has any solution to this problem?

Thanks for any help or hints.
Mario_S

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. Xen 4.2.1 shipped with Ubuntu 13.04 has a bug in the xl toolstack (you are using xl?) that prevents a reboot of the HVM guest.

A work around is to use the xm toolstack (you need to enable it), or to upgrade Xen - see also [Xen stable update to 4.2.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xen/+bug/1180397)

Also, [this Xen mailing list thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.xen.user/77515) sheds some light on the xl bug, with a recommendation to use xm when trying VGA passthru.